# Algebraic Morse theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

In 2005, prof. Emil Skoldberg developed a theory, similar to Forman's Discrete Morse Theory, but suited for arbitrary based chain complexes, in his [*Morse Theory from an algebraic viewpoint*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/skoldberg.pdf). I'm going through the paper and am having some difficulties.

**Question 1:** On p. 116, in the definition of a *Morse matching*, there is written:

> We call a partial matching $M$ on the digraph $G_K$ a *Morse matching* if
> for each edge $\alpha\to\beta\in M$ the corresponding component $d_{\beta,\alpha}$ is an
> isomorphism, and furthermore, there is a well-founded partial order $\preceq$
> on each $I_n$ such that $\alpha\succ\gamma$ **whenever** there is a path $\alpha^{(n)}\to\beta\to\gamma^{(n)}$ in $G^M_K$.

Is $\preceq$ defined by "exists a path $\alpha^{(n)}\to\beta\to\gamma^{(n)}$ in $G^M_K$", or is that just a necessary condition on $\preceq$? More precisely, the word "whenever" in the above quote, is that meant as $\Leftarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$?

**Question 2:** In the proof of Theorem 2 on p. 121. How do Lemmas 3 and 4 imply that for $x\!\in\!K_\alpha$ with $\alpha\!\in\!M_n^0$ there holds $$\rho\pi(x)=x?$$ We have $\rho\pi(x)=\rho(x)-\rho\phi d(x)-\rho d\phi(x)$. Since $x\!\in\!C_n$ and $\rho$ is a projection, we have $\rho(x)=x$. By Lemma 3, we have $d\phi(x)\!=\!0$. By Lemma 4, we have $\phi d(x) = \sum_{\beta\preceq\alpha}y_\beta=:(\ast)$ for some $y_\beta\!\in\!K_\beta$, but why is $(\ast)=0$ when $\alpha$ is critical?

**Question 3:** In Corollary 3, in the first sum, $\sigma$ ranges through $M^0_{n-1}$, right?

P.S. I might later add additional questions regarding p.116-122.

Comment: [Also on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118946/).